# DrawRectangle doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, class, drawing

I have a rectangle on a class created by me. The function "DrawRectangle" doesn't draw anything. I put the code below:

My own class (Unidad.cs):

```
class Unidad
{
    //Constructor
    public Unidad(string tipo, int movimiento)
    {
        tipoUnidad = tipo;
        movimientoUnidad = movimiento;
    }

    //Propiedades
    public string tipoUnidad {get; set;}
    public int movimientoUnidad { get; set; }

    //Método para dibujar unidad
    public void colocar(MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        Form1 myf = new Form1();

        using (Graphics g = myf.picboxFondo.CreateGraphics())
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

            g.DrawRectangle(pen, e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);

            pen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Prueba de clase
    Unidad prueba;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picboxFondo.Size = ClientRectangle.Size;
        prueba = new Unidad("I", 20);
    }

    private void picboxFondo_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        prueba.colocar(e);
    }
}
```

I have picboxFondo Modifiers public. All compile correctly and works perfect, but when I go to g.DrawRectangle I see all the values are OK but it doesn't draw anything.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Right now you are creating a new instance of your form and creating a graphics context on the new instance on every MouseDown. You are drawing the rectangle to a new form every time and from what I can see you're not even showing the new form.

Comment: oh, no, i don't want to do that! I want to create a Rectangle from my "Unidad" class. Can you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a *new instance* of your `Form1` class and try to draw on the `PictureBox` of that new instance (which isn't shown at all).

Instead you can pass the control you want to draw on as a parameter to your `colocar` method:

```
public void colocar(Point p, Control control)
{
    using (Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics())
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, p.X, p.Y, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like that in your form:

```
private void picboxFondo_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    prueba.colocar(e.Location, picboxFondo);
}
```

---

I also changed the method so that you only pass the `Location` of the `MouseEventArgs`, because your drawing method doesn't need to know anything about mouse events, only about the `Point`.
And note that there is no need to call `Dispose` on the `Pen` or the `Graphics`, the `using` statement is doing that for you.
And you may consider using the [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) and rename your method `Colocar`.